# Use Python to monitor a program then make input once certain perameters are met?

Tags: python, python-3.x, helios

If there is already a post with this kind of information somewhere, please link it and I will gladly use that information. I tried my best to research it and haven't been able to find anything concrete.

That being said, I guess I should start with *is it possible?*

What I'm looking to do is write a python script that will monitor a program, then once certain parameters are met, I want the python script to make certain inputs on the program. To be more specific, I want to use a python script that monitors the program "PredatorSense" from Acer, and once certain temperatures are reached, I want the script to automatically change the fan speed to an rpm I specify once these temperatures are met. This is doable manually through this software, but it usually happens i'm playing a game so i'd have to minimize the game, change the speeds, then switch back.

To answer a question i'm sure some reading this may ask "Why not just have the fans set to auto and then let the program do it's thing?" well my answer to that question is this: The program doesn't let the fans get to certain speeds unless in "turbo" mode, which keeps the fans at max speeds the entire time, which are really loud. I'd like to only have them at max speeds when necessary to keep below a certain temp.

If the question was asked poorly, please feel free to let me know so I can word it better. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: (I wonder if it might be easier to find a different fan control program.. the 'input' from the "PredatorSense" is itself, likely going to be an issue to deal with, given nothing else.)

Comment: (ps. assuming it is a laptop, it might be worth exploring 'cooling pads' and letting the fans/TDP do their thing. or [even perhaps adjust the motherboard settings like this](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/533592/overheating-fan-control-solution-cpu-gpu). 0.02.)